NextJS export function instead of object
In NextJS I have the following server function:
'use server'

import { fetchWrapper } from "@/utils/fetchWrapper";

const getPosts = async() : Promise<any[]> => {
    var posts = await fetchWrapper.get('api/posts');
    return posts;
}

export const postService = { getPosts };

I want to use it in a client component:
"use client"

import { postService } from "@/services/postService";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

console.log("postService: ", postService);

export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const results = await postService.getPosts();
      console.log('results : ', results);
      setPosts(results);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>
      {posts && posts.map(post => 
        <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>
      )}
    </h1>
  );
}

My console log displays:
postService:  ƒ () {
    // $FlowFixMe[method-unbinding]
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return callServer(id, args);
  }

followed by the error:
page.tsx:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _services_postService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.postService.getPosts is not a function

From my understanding postService is being exported as a function instead of an object. Why is this happening?

import { getPosts } from "@/services/postService"; matches your export statement.

Next.js expects you to only export async functions from files that starts with "use server". You should export getPosts instead of postService.
export const getPosts = async() : Promise<any[]> => {
    var posts = await fetchWrapper.get('api/posts');
    return posts;
}

Then if you want to import them as a group you can:
import { getPosts } from "@/services/postService"
// or
import * as postService from "@/services/postService"

await postService.getPosts();


For your information, Server Actions is for mutating and not good for fetching data as it runs in sequence not in parallel. You can refactor your code to fetch the data in a Server Component and move interactivity to a nested Client Component:
export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await fetchWrapper.get('api/posts');

  return (
    <h1>
      {posts && posts.map(post => 
        <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>
      )}
    </h1>
  );
}


I have an external REST API. How should I approach structuring my NextJS application? Currently I have a fetchWrapper file for GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. Then I use those methods in server components as you showed above. Is this the common approach?

This issue only occurs on files starts with "use server".
